# Converting PDF, Doc and Docx to rtf in c#

Tags: c#, document-conversion

I have a requirement for an application that takes Doc, Docx and PDF and converts them to RTF.

The conversion is one way and I do not need to convert back to Doc or PDF.

Has anyone done this and can you recommend a libray?  I know there is aspose but it's way to pricey and the licenses are per year so that's not going to work for the company I happen to work for.

I'm ok using more than one library for each of the file types if thats what it takes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has a nice library to do this.  They actually have an entire editor that looks like Microsoft Word.  It can open multiple file formats and it saves natively as RTF (although it can save as PDF, DOCX, etc.)  The one thing I'm not sure of is opening the PDF and saving as an RTF.  I'm not sure that the Telerik library can do that.

Here is a link to the library:
http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/richtextbox.aspx

For a PDF to RTF library, you could use this:
http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/index.php

Comment: I actually just need a library to open the PDF and spit out RTF.  I can then do the saving.  It's the conversion I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

[GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud](https://products.groupdocs.cloud/conversion) is a REST API that converts all common file formats from on format to another reliably and easily. Its free pricing plan offers 50 free credits per month.

Here is sample code for PDF to RTF from default storage:

```
// Get App Key and App SID from https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud/
var configuration = new GroupDocs.Conversion.Cloud.Sdk.Client.Configuration(MyAppSid, MyAppKey);
var apiInstance = new ConvertApi(configuration);

try
{
    // convert settings
    var settings = new GroupDocs.Conversion.Cloud.Sdk.Model.ConvertSettings
    {
        StorageName = null,
        FilePath = "02_pages.pdf",
        Format = "rtf",
        ConvertOptions = new RtfConvertOptions(),
        OutputPath = "02_pages.rtf"
    };

    // convert to specified format
    List<StoredConvertedResult> response = apiInstance.ConvertDocument(new ConvertDocumentRequest(settings));
    Console.WriteLine("Document converted successfully: " + response[0].Url);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception when calling ConvertApi.QuickConvert: " + e.Message);
}
```

I'm developer evangelist at aspose.